# Unexpected EOF using Go http client

Tags: http, error-handling, go

I am learning Go and came across this problem.

I am just downloading web page content using HTTP client:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://mail.ru/", nil)
    req.Close = true

    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(content)[:100])
}
```

I get an `unexpected EOF` error when reading response body. At the same time content variable has full page content.

This error appear only when I downloading `https://mail.ru/` content. With other URLs everything works fine - without any errors.

I used curl for downloading this page content - everything works as expected.

I am confused a bit - what's happening here?

Go v1.2, tried on Ubuntu and MacOS X

Comment: Maybe mail.ru returns a broken Content-Length? Check the whole response manually. Curl "just works" and won't complain on little quirks.

Comment: The server doesn't send a Content-Length header and simply disconnects the client when it is done sending the response. This leads to an "unexpected EOF" because the client didn't know that's going to happen - but that's perfectly fine apparently. The content is received in tact.

Comment: Response has a Content-Length header. I've manually checked Content-Length header value and actual length of response - they are equal.

Comment: Strange, when I run your code I don't get one.

Comment: hmm.. yep, this is strange, maybe another Go version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the that server (Apache 1.3, wow!) is serving up a truncated gzip response. If you explicitly request the `identity` encoding (preventing the Go transport from adding `gzip` itself), you won't get the `ErrUnexpectedEOF`:

```
req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity")
```

Comment: A side note: The "identity" encoding is acceptable by default - if not explicitly suppressed (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding#Directives).